# Error using lmfit v0_9_3

Tags: python, numpy, lmfit

I'm somewhat new to using python for data analysis, and to using lmfit for non-linear equation fitting. I am attempting to model a complex semi-analytical function that describes the movement of a pollutant plume in a 1D channel over time. I'm using lmfit v0.9.3. I've successfully worked through several examples from the lmfit tutorials, but cannot seem to get my own model working. The script below, works up to the `tsm_mod.fit()` call, but then returns the error:

> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 501, in
>   fit
>       for p in params.values()])
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
from lmfit import Model

desmedt = pd.read_table('Directory\desmedt_test.txt',sep='\t')

x = desmedt['Times']
y = desmedt['Conc']

def tsm_intfunc(t,x,tau,u,k,alpha,beta,mass,ac):
    return((mass/(2*ac*(t*np.pi*k)**(1/2)))*np.exp(-((x-u*t)**2)/(4*k*t))*np.exp(-alpha*tau-alpha*(t-tau)/beta)
        *np.sqrt(beta*tau/(t-tau))*sp.special.iv(2*np.sqrt((alpha**2)*tau*(t-tau)/beta),1))

def tsm_desmedt(t,x,u,k,alpha,beta,mass,ac,nsteps):   
    dtau = t/nsteps
    cxt = (mass/(2*ac*np.sqrt(t*np.pi*k)))*np.exp(-((x-u*t)**2)/(4*k*t))*np.exp(-alpha*t)
    cxv = tsm_intfunc(t,x,0.00000001,u,k,alpha,beta,mass,ac)/2
    i = 1

    while (i<nsteps):
        cxv = cxv+tsm_intfunc(t,x,dtau*i,u,k,alpha,beta,mass,ac)/2
        i = i+1

    return cxt+(alpha/beta)*cxv*dtau

tsm_mod = Model(tsm_desmedt)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('ac',value=18.2,vary=False)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('alpha',value=1e-4)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('beta',value=1e-1)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('k',value=3)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('mass',value=157100,vary=False)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('nsteps',value=100,vary=False)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('u',value=0.4)
tsm_mod.set_param_hint('x',value=4604,vary=False)

tsm_pars = tsm_mod.make_params()
tsm_fit = tsm_mod.fit(y,x,tsm_pars)
```

Could this be a bug in lmfit? Or, do you think there is an error in the way I've set up the problem using lmfit?

**Edit:** 
The data used in the fitting is given below:

*Times*

> 7787.628
>   8330.04 8640
>   8756.244
>   8988.696
>   9143.676
>   9337.392
>   9492.372
>   9724.86
>   9918.576
>   10034.784
>   10228.536
>   10383.516
>   10577.232
>   10770.948
>   11003.4
>   11119.644
>   11313.36
>   11468.34
>   11700.792
>   11855.772
>   12010.752
>   12204.468
>   12359.448
>   12630.672
>   12824.388
>   13173.084
>   13483.044
>   13793.004
>   14412.924
>   14955.336
>   15575.256
>   16195.14
>   17357.472

*Conc*

> 0.00944669
>   0.0850202
>   0.236167
>   0.576248
>   1.00135
>   2.01215
>   2.84345
>   3.51417
>   4.53441
>   5.21457
>   5.59244
>   5.74359
>   5.88529
>   6.0081
>   5.75304
>   5.61134
>   5.20513
>   4.95007
>   4.41161
>   3.74089
>   3.46694
>   3.07962
>   2.80567
>   2.41835
>   2.1444
>   1.74764
>   1.47368
>   1.20918
>   0.935223
>   0.661269
>   0.406208
>   0.132254
>   0.11336
>   0.151147

Comment: Could you provide the data you are using or at least a subset of it?

Comment: According to the [docs online](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#model.Model), `Model.fit` expects to be passed args data, params, weights, ...; you've given it y, x, tsm\_pars, which doesn't look obviously right to me. In particular, it's going to be treating your `x` as its `params`, which it expects to be a `Parameters` object.

Comment: Just going by what I see on the web -- I've never used py-lmfit myself -- I think perhaps you want something like `tsm_fit = tsm_mod.fit(y, tsm_pars, x=x)`.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the data used in the fit. This is the data that is imported from the desmedt textfile. Also, I believe that I got it working: I failed to realize that the format suggested by Gareth requires a pointer to the independent variable in the function arguments list, as it is written in the arguments:
tsm_fit=tsm_mod.fit(y, tsm_pars, t=x)
Thank you each for your prompt replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is slightly confusing in that your model function contains both an independent variable `t` and a variable `x`, and in your main program you call the times `x`.   Anyway, the call you want is

```
tsm_fit = tsm_mod.fit(y, tsm_pars, t=x)
```

The fit seems to not work well, but that appears to be a separate issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the input. I had realized the error in my code and was able to successfully implement it (see comment above). However, the model has parameter identifiability problems, hence the poor fit if the initial parameter guesses are far off from their optimal values. Interestingly, I've also implemented this algorithm in R, and was able to get a better fit (with the LMFit Package) with parameter values closer to what they should be in less time than with Python. Most interesting is  Excel Solver gives the best estimate of the parameter values, but cannot report on standard errors.